# Website scraping in python, but the class has a varying class name. (discord.py aswell)

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, discord.py, python-re

I'm trying to scrape the match details on "flashscore.com", for example "https://www.flashscore.com/match/hEyZ9RHu/#match-summary", and then reuse them in an embed on discord. Basically all of this is being done through a discord bot, but that doesn't really matter right now. I'm trying to get one of the person's full name, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def analize(ctx, link):
    if ctx.guild is not None:
            await ctx.send("Scraping...")
            html=requests.get(link)
            soup=BeautifulSoup(html.text,"html.parser")
            name=soup.find_all('a', class_=re.compile("participantName___"))
            print(name)
```

that is my code, but all it prints out is []. I'm really new to python, web scraping and programming in general, so sorry if i'm not understanding something.

but why does this not work? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the SoupStrainer object, which filters out any unnecessary html

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
```

You just need to pass in an extra parameter to you BeatifulSoup object, called parse_only, and this should contain your SoupStrainer object. You could then iterate over all the a tag elements, and see if there class contains "participantName", if there is, you can add the href, that contains the participants name.

```
participants = []
strainer = SoupStrainer("a")
soup = BeatifulSoup(html.text "html.parser", parse_only=strainer)
for elem in soup.find_all("a"):
    try:
       class_ = elem["class"]
    
    except:
        continue
    if "participantName" in class_:
        participants.append(elem["href"])
```

Comment: class = elem["class"] shows a syntax error on the =

Comment: @LukezasZ try it now, all I did was change the name of the variable 'class' to 'class_' since 'class' is a reserved keyword in Python. Let me know if it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want more than the whole page request is the HTML headers. A quick inspect shows that the names are listed in the headers under `<meta name="og:title" content="Timofey Yusipov - Vladimir Marshalov 0:3">`. Use the requests.head() function, then print the headers. Once you see some particular pattern, then parse using BeautifulSoup or even just using a `for` loop through the headers, looking for the "og-title" meta.

I'm new to HTML so I am not sure how to phrase that last part.

Comment: I tried doing that, didn't end up making it work aswell, but eventually thought of changing it to this way, since I'd need to seperate the player names for further reasons.

Comment: Hm, okay. Try taking a closer look at the data you're getting; print it out, make sure it has what you want in it.